# Ditto's equivalent in Mac

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, copy-paste, utilities

can you help me find an equivalent clipboard management programs in OS X?

I am used to how Ditto- clipboard manager (copy-paste stack) works and was unable to search for a replacement using "ditto Mac" as search terms.

Comment: Other related questions: http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=clipboard+history

Comment: @EladBenda This article maybe helpful http://gigaom.com/2009/06/02/10-clipboard-managers-for-os-x/